# Trouble with expressing $(a+b)^z$ as an integral over the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to derive the identity

$(a+b)^z = \int_C \frac{ds}{2\pi i} \frac{\Gamma(-s) \Gamma(s-z)}{\Gamma(-z)} a^{-s+z}b^{z}$

where the contour is given according to the figure below[image] Specifically, my problem is with the integration contour. I'm confused if it is more similar to the case (i) of http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.17 or either (ii) or (iii) depending on if $a>b$ or $a<b$. I don't think I can consider all the poles because one of the two resulting series will not converge.

For more context, I'm trying to derive eq. (A2) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0211056.pdf and make sense of the comments below.

Comment: Did you try something like this ? For $|x| < 1$ : $(1-x)^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {z \choose k} (-x)^k =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{ \Gamma(z+1-k)}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} x^k$ $ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty Res(\Gamma(-s)\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1-s)} x^s,k)$ $ =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_\lambda \Gamma(-s)\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1-s)} x^sds$ where $\lambda$ encloses the positive real axis

Comment: The appendix at the end of your link explains how to extend to $|x| > 1$ by changing the contour.